# Laravel 8 and PHPMiler

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmailer, send

I want to send forms via Phpmailer to Laravel, taking them from my modal window that appears on js.The data from the form should always come to the same email

How I did:

-installed phpmailer via composer (composer require phpmailer/phpmailer)

-Created a controller (php artisan make:controller ContactController)

-Created a router on the web.php

-In env registered his mail password (application password) and mail login

What is the error , what actions have I forgotten or done incorrectly

```
                                             My code in Laravel
```

HTML    My modalWindow

Title
      
       
        @csrf
           
            
              input type="text" class="name" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="Имя"   required>

```
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="name" class="form-label"></label>
           <input type="text" class="name" id="phone" name="phone"  placeholder="+1(***)-***-**-**"  required>
         </div>

         <div class="mb-3">
           <button class="btn-modal" type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
         </div>
         </form>
        </div>

          <div class ="modalEl">
           <button class="btn-modal" id="close-modal">Close</button>
          </div>
```

web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;

Route::post('/send',[ContactController::class,'send'])->name('email.send');
```

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request) {

        $name = $request->name;
        $phone = $request->phone;


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = env('EMAIL_HOST');
        $mail->SMTPAuth = 'true';
        $mail->Username = env('EMAIL_USERNAME');
        $mail->Password = env('email_password');
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->setFrom('','$name');
        $mail->addAddress('my@email.com');
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = '';
        $mail-> Body = $phone;
       $result =  $mail->send();
       if($result) {
           echo 'sucessful';
       }else{
           echo'error'; 
       }
```

my ENV

```
EMAIL_HOST= smtp.yandex.ru
EMAIL_PORT=465
EMAIL_USERNAME=myemail@yandex.ru
EMAIL_PASSWORD= myPassword
```

( email password for applications)

Comment: We ask you "what is the error you are getting?" have you checked the logs? the network response....

Comment: You don't actually say what's wrong; your code looks fine. One minor (and probably unrelated) thing is that you shouldn't use `env()` in controller code because it production mode it will not return anything. Use `env()` *only* in your config files, and then get the values from `config()` instead of `env()`.